# Rails OmniAuth NoMethodError with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I've been following [this](http://blog.railsrumble.com/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth/) tutorial for setting up OmniAuth with facebook, however when I try to run /auth/facebook, I get an error as follows:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My code is the same as the one in the tutorial, except

```
auth = request.env['rack.auth']
```

is changed to

```
auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are a bit dated. Try [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) instead.